# Android apollo subscriptions not working?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, graphql-subscriptions, apollo-android

I need to integrate `subscription` in my Android app. The `subscription` works fine on `localhost` in `graphiql`. I have deployed my backend on Heroku. I am using `apollo-server` and not `hasura`.
My `subscriptions` are not working for the url given by `Heroku` but it works fine on `localhost`. `Queries` and `mutations` work fine for both `localhost` and `Heroku` url.
So I am trying to access my subscription from my Android client. I have kept the base url as my local host. I have configured my Android emulator correctly for `localhost` and the `queries` and `mutations` part works for my Android client but my subscription part is not working.

I have configured my `Apollo` client for `subscription` by adding this

```
.subscriptionTransportFactory(WebSocketSubscriptionTransport.Factory(baseUrl,okHttpClient))
```

My subscription code looks as follows

```
val healthConsultationSubscriptionList = GetHealthConsultationSubscription.builder().build()
        apolloClient.subscribe(healthConsultationSubscriptionList).execute(object :
            ApolloSubscriptionCall.Callback<GetHealthConsultationSubscription.Data> {
            override fun onFailure(e: ApolloException) {
                Log.i("datafailure","${e.message} ${e.localizedMessage} ${e.cause}" )
            }

            override fun onResponse(response: Response<GetHealthConsultationSubscription.Data>) {
                Log.i("datais", response.data()?.healthConsultation()?.chiefComplaint().toString() )
            }

            override fun onConnected() {
                Log.i("dataconnected","Connected")
            }

            override fun onTerminated() {
                Log.i("dataterminated","Terminated")
            }

            override fun onCompleted() {
                Log.i("datacompleted","Completed")
            }

        })
```

But I keep getting an error saying `Subscription failed Subscription failed java.net.ProtocolException: Expected HTTP 101 response but was '400 Bad Request'`

Also when I use Graphiql for my subscription and replace localhost with the Heroku url for my subscription , I get following error.

[image]

Are these two issues which I am facing are related to one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there was no problem from my  Code. The issue was with the free tier of `Heroku` I am using. I tried replacing my subscription with `Hasura's` Subscription https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/android/subscriptions/1-subscription/ and it works.